# Change last character of (n) to another char in java

Tags: java

i'm just created java program to show string as matrix in java and finally it's done. But i have a problem which is about to change the last character if **rows x colum > str.charAt(n)** (total matrix is define from string length), so the total matrix is based on string length you have. Here's the output i wanna make:

**Matrix 5x6 -> Total row(30)**
**String = "This my first time to doit -> String length(27) including space character"** I wanna change the last three character to be underscore '_' like display below:

```
o _ d o i t 
t y _ f i _ 
_ m T h r _ 
e _ s i s _ 
m i t _ t _
```

But the output i just made is like below:

```
o _ d o i t 
t y _ f i _ 
_ m T h r T 
e _ s i s T 
m i t _ t T
```

From the display above, i know that the last char is taken from str.char(1) first character = 'T'

I want to ask you, for example **if total matrix is 30, and string length is 26**, how to change the last 4 char into '_'?

```
Here's my code:
for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i ){
        for ( int j = 0; j < cols; ++j ){
            int n = matrix[i][j];

            System.out.print(replaceStr.charAt(n) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Can somebody help me through this? Thank you

Comment: what does it mean : rows x cols > str.charAt(n) , here are u comparing with ascii values or a number as you are getting from a matrix?

Comment: I mean, if total matrix is 30, and total string is 28. I want to change to last two with '_'

Comment: what total string 28 mean is it n or length of  replaceStr ?  Reason being to ask question is not clear to me

Comment: Yes, string length is 28, and total matrix is 30. Sorry if my explanation is confusing

Comment: Try to clear your question again

Comment: Is it clear? @Eklavya

Answer (score 0):

check the length of the string:

```
if ( n < replaceStr.length()  ) {
    System.out.print(replaceStr.charAt(n) + " ");
} else {
    System.out.print("_ ");
}
```

Update: full test with a simple matrix:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "This my first time to doit ";
        String replaceStr = str.replace(' ','_');

        int rows = 5;
        int columns = 6;
        int matrix[][] = new int[rows][columns];

        // create a simple matrix
        int index = 0;
        for (int i=00; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j< columns; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = index;
                index++;
            }
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i ){
            for ( int j = 0; j < columns; ++j ){
                int n = matrix[i][j];
                if(n < 26 ) {
                    System.out.print(replaceStr.charAt(n) + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("_ ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
T h i s _ m 
y _ f i r s 
t _ t i m e 
_ t o _ d o 
i t _ _ _ _
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but your code is changing every string to '_'

Comment: Is replaceStr not the input string? If it does this to every character, Is repalceStr an empty string? I just tried it with a simple matrix (filled it with increasing numbers) and it seems to work in my test..

Comment: No it isn't, it define statically

Comment: What's the input string? where do you get the data from?

Comment: public static String str = "This my first time to doit ";
public static String replaceStr = str.replace(' ','_');

Comment: Then it should work if matrix[i][j] contains a value between 0 and the string length.

Comment: For another word is, change the rest of duplicate to another character

Comment: I updated my answer to a complete test. Like I said, it works fine on my machine. How do you create the matrix?

Comment: Not work to me, the last value keep showing value of first index

Comment: What the value of the matrix? If it's actually containing a "0" it's working as it should, since then there is no way to determine a valid value from an invalid one... How do you create the matrix? I guess that's where the problem is, not the output.

Comment: My guess is, that you init your matrix with 0, or don't set the values for the latter entries of the matrix. Since only the value of a matrix spot is relevant, the code works, but your matrix doesn't represent the transformation you want (by transforming empty entries to index 0).

Comment: On a related note, could you please accept the answer in this old question of yours, by clicking on the checkmarl next to the question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62651435/printing-string-in-rows-and-column-pattern-java

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ask you, for example if total matrix is 30, and string
> length is 26, how to change the last 4 char into '_'?

Put a condition `if(n < 26 ) {...} else {...}` as shown below:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i ){
    for ( int j = 0; j < cols; ++j ){
        int n = matrix[i][j];
        if(n < 26 ) {
            System.out.print(replaceStr.charAt(n) + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("_ ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```